# Issues using table result from SQL function vs table result from SQL View in further QUERY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, temp-tables, sql-view

I have the situation in which i am trying to return a result set from a SQL function into a temporary table and then utilise this temp table in a further query.

Initially the query was using an SQL View to return a result set and use that in the query however i am now trying to make this a little more efficient so i have change the view to be an sql function to allow parameters to be able to query on a subset of the data rather then return everything in the view.

When i run the new sql function and compare agains the original view everything aligns however when i replace this SQL view (in the main SQL query) with the new SQL function it starts doing some strange things.

I have included a snippet of what the query is (NOTE i have removed the actual name and replaced with temp names)

```
        declare @parm1 varchar(2) = ''  ; 
        declare  @ResultSet table (  
            col int,   
            col1 varChar(2),   
            col2 int,   
            col3 int,   
            col4 int,   
            col5 varChar(10),   
            col6 int,   
            col7 int,   
            col8 int,   
            col9 int,   
            col10 decimal(38,1),   
            col11 float,   
            col12 float)  

        insert into @ResultSet  
        Select col, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12 FROM udfFunction(@parm1) 
        --Select col, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12 FROM wvView 

        SELECT v1.col, v1.col1, v1.col13, v1.col5, v1.col4, v2.col14, v1.col15, v1.col16, v1.col17, v1.col8, v1.col9,    
                        COALESCE (TP.col12, TS.col12, TW.col12, TV.col12, TA.col12, 0.40) AS col12,    
                        COALESCE (SP.col11, SS.col11, SW.col11, SV.col11, SA.col11, CASE WHEN v1.col5 = 'CODE' THEN 4 ELSE 22 END) AS col11,    
                        COALESCE (TP.col12, TS.col12, TW.col12, TV.col12, TA.col12, 0.40) * (v1.col17 - v1.col9) AS field1,    
                        COALESCE (SP.col11, SS.col11, SW.col11, SV.col11, SA.col11, CASE WHEN v1.col5 = 'CODE' THEN 4 ELSE 22 END) * (v1.col14 - v1.col16) * 227 AS field2   
                    FROM wba.ivView1 AS v1   
                    INNER JOIN dbo.View2 AS v2 ON v2.col14 = v1.col14   
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN @ResultSet AS SP ON SP.col = v1.col And SP.col1 = v1.col1 And SP.col4 = v1.col4 And SP.col2 = v2.col2 And SP.col3 = v2.col3 And SP.col7 = v2.col7 And SP.col6 = v2.col6 And SP.col5 = v1.col5    
                LEFT OUTER JOIN @ResultSet AS SS ON SS.col = v1.col AND SS.col1 = v1.col1 AND SS.col4 = v1.col4 AND SS.col2 = v2.col2 AND SS.col3 = v2.col3 AND SS.col7 = v2.col7 AND SS.col6 IS NULL AND SS.col5 = v1.col5    
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN @ResultSet AS SW ON SW.col = v1.col And SW.col1 = v1.col1 And SW.col4 = v1.col4 And SW.col2 = v2.col2 And SW.col3 = v2.col3 And SW.col7 Is NULL And SW.col6 Is NULL And SW.col5 = v1.col5    
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN @ResultSet AS SV ON SV.col = v1.col AND SV.col1 IS NULL AND SV.col4 = v1.col4 AND SV.col2 = v2.col2 AND SV.col3 = v2.col3 AND SV.col7 = v2.col7 AND SV.col6 IS NULL AND SV.col5 = v1.col5    
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN @ResultSet AS SA ON SA.col = v1.col And SA.col1 Is NULL And SA.col4 = v1.col4 And SA.col2 = v2.col2 And SA.col3 = v2.col3 And SA.col7 Is NULL And SA.col6 Is NULL And SA.col5 = v1.col5    
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN @ResultSet AS TP ON TP.col = v1.col AND TP.col1 = v1.col1 AND TP.col4 = v1.col4 AND TP.col2 = v2.col2 AND TP.col3 = v2.col3 AND TP.col7 = v2.col7 AND TP.col6 = v2.col6 AND TP.col5 IS NULL    
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN @ResultSet AS TS ON TS.col = v1.col And TS.col1 = v1.col1 And TS.col4 = v1.col4 And TS.col2 = v2.col2 And TS.col3 = v2.col3 And TS.col7 = v2.col7 And TS.col6 Is NULL And TS.col5 Is NULL    
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN @ResultSet AS TW ON TW.col = v1.col AND TW.col1 = v1.col1 AND TW.col4 = v1.col4 AND TW.col2 = v2.col2 AND TW.col3 = v2.col3 AND TW.col7 IS NULL AND TW.col6 IS NULL AND TW.col5 IS NULL    
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN @ResultSet AS TV ON TV.col = v1.col And TV.col1 Is NULL And TV.col4 = v1.col4 And TV.col2 = v2.col2 And TV.col3 = v2.col3 And TV.col7 = v2.col7 And TV.col6 Is NULL    
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN @ResultSet AS TA ON TA.col = v1.col AND TA.col1 IS NULL AND TA.col4 = v1.col4 AND TA.col2 = v2.col2 AND TA.col3 = v2.col3 AND TA.col7 IS NULL AND TA.col6 IS NULL   
                    WHERE (v1.col1 = parm1 or parm1 = '') and ((v1.cm_Count > v1.col8) OR (v1.col8 = 0))   
                    order by col5
```

When trouble shoot this the and if interchange the two "select" after then "insert" it the contents of @ResultsSet are the same - the issue is however when this result set is applied to the JOINs further down it seems to play up if the @resultset has been populated using the SQL function - i am at a loss as to why this is happening.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

As per request by here is what is being used to create the sql function and sql view

sql view

```
            create view [schema].[wvView] with schemabinding as  
        Select v2.col1, v2.col2, col3, col4, v2.col5, v2.col6, v3.col7, v3.col8, (sum(v2.col9)) As col9, sum(col10) As col10,   
                sum(v1.col11) AS col11, cast(sum(v1.col11) AS float) / 100 / sum(v2.col9) AS col12, cast(sum(v1.col11) AS float) / sum(v2.col10) AS col13  
        FROM schema.ivView1 v1
        INNER JOIN schema.ivView2 v2 ON v2.col1 = v1.col1 AND v2.col2 = v1.col2 AND v2.col5 = v1.col5 AND v2.col6 = v1.col6 AND v2.col14 = v1.col14   
        INNER JOIN dbo.wvView3 v3 ON v3.col14 = v2.col14  
        WHERE  v2.col10 > 0  
        GROUP BY grouping sets(  
                            (v2.col1, v2.col2, col3, col4, v2.col5),   
                            (v2.col1, v2.col2, col3, col4, v2.col5, v2.col6),   
                            (v2.col1, col3, col4, v2.col5, col8),   
                            (v2.col1, col3, col4, v2.col5),   
                            (v2.col1, v2.col2, col3, col4, v2.col5, col8),   
                            (v2.col1, v2.col2, col3, col4, v2.col5, v2.col6, col8),   
                            (v2.col1, v2.col2, col3, col4, v2.col5, col8, v3.col7),   
                            (v2.col1, v2.col2, col3, col4, v2.col5, v2.col6, col8, v3.col7)  
        )
```

sql function

```
       create function schema.udfFunction(parm1 as varchar(2))  
    returns @rtnTable table ( 
    col1 int,  
    col2 varchar(2),  
    col3 bit,  
    col4 bit, 
    col5 bit,  
    col6 varchar(10),  
    col7 int,  
    col8 int,  
    col9 int,  
    col10 int,  
    col11 decimal(38,1),  
    col12 float,  
    col13 float)  
    AS  
    BEGIN  
       declare @tmp as varchar(2) = parm1;  
       insert into @rtnTable  
                Select v2.col1, v2.col2, col3, col4, v2.col5, v2.col6, v3.col7, v3.col8, (sum(v2.col9)) As col9, sum(col10) As col10,    
                sum(v1.col11) AS col11, cast(sum(v1.col11) AS float) / 100 / sum(v2.col9) AS col12, cast(sum(v1.col11) AS float) / sum(v2.col10) AS col13   
                FROM schema.ivView1 v1    
                INNER JOIN schema.ivView2 v2 ON v2.col1 = v1.col1 AND v2.col2 = v1.col2 AND v2.col5 = v1.col5 AND v2.col6 = v1.col6 AND v2.col14 = v1.col14    
                INNER JOIN dbo.wvView3 v3 ON v3.col14 = v2.col14   
                WHERE  v2.col10 > 0 and (v2.col2 = @tmp or @tmp = '')   
                GROUP BY grouping sets(   
                                    (v2.col1, v2.col2, col3, col4, v2.col5),  
                                    (v2.col1, v2.col2, col3, col4, v2.col5, v2.col6),    
                                    (v2.col1, col3, col4, v2.col5, col8),  
                                    (v2.col1, col3, col4, v2.col5),    
                                    (v2.col1, v2.col2, col3, col4, v2.col5, col8),    
                                    (v2.col1, v2.col2, col3, col4, v2.col5, v2.col6, col8),  
                                    (v2.col1, v2.col2, col3, col4, v2.col5, col8, v3.col7),    
                                    (v2.col1, v2.col2, col3, col4, v2.col5, v2.col6, col8, v3.col7)  
                )  
        return  
    END
```

also here is the definition of the view from MSSQL

[MSSQL View Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAIal.png)

which i have noticed has one column different so will edit that and see how i go.

Thanks

Comment: After you changed your view to function, did you check if all the columns are returning with the correct data types ? I see that you are using some floats and decimals for some of the columns in @ResultSet so if you are loosing some data after it returns from the function, for some parameter you didn't really compare to view, one of your joins might fail and you might get a different result from coalesce. So can you also add the view and the function for comparison ?

Comment: also i thought i worth mentioning when i was creating the table definition (for the function) i reviewed the view columns to make sure they were actually the same

Answer (score 0):

solution was to make sure all columns in both the function and view were of the same type once done everything worked as expected.